# ReactJs lazy when trying to use lazy loading, getting 'window; is not defined error

Tags: reactjs, webpack, lazy-loading

import React, { Component, lazy, Suspense } from 'react';

// import MyComp from './Components/myComp';
const MyComp = lazy(() => import('./components/myComp'));

500 Internal Server Error
Error while loading "~/Content/Scripts/dist/server.js": ReferenceError: 'window' is not defined at Anonymous function (server.js:1:1832) -> …o.p="",o.oe=function(e){throw console.error(e),e};var a=window.webpackJsonp=window.webpackJsonp||[],… at Global code (server.js:1:1)

Answer (score 0):

You have to use loadable https://github.com/gregberge/loadable-components instead of React.lazy. React.lazy doesn't work when you have server side rendering.

```
import loadable from '@loadable/component'
// This dynamic import will not be processed server-side
const Other = loadable(() => import('./Other'), { ssr: false })
```

Comment: `import React from 'react';  
import loadable from '@loadable/component';  
import Loading from './Loading';  

const LoadableComponent = loadable(() => import('./OtherComponent'), {
    fallback: <Loading />,
});` Still getting same error, also console throws error "Uncaught ReferenceError: jQuery is not defined"

Comment: I updated the answer, have you added ssr: false? Not sure how jquery is related to it )

Comment: I do not use ssr

Comment: I am using react js with asp.net , there is no option ssr in webpack.config.js